# Bash descriptors in sub shell

Tags: bash, file-descriptor

The snippet below was intended to listen and select a few songs from a directory:

```
exec 3<&1

find /some/directory -name '*.mp3' -print0 | xargs -0 bash -c '
    for i; do
        mplayer -ss 10 "$i" 1<&3
        read -p "Select? (y/n)" -n 1 choice 1<&3
        if [ "$choice" = "y" -o "$choice" = "Y" ]; then
            echo "$i" > /tmp/selected_songs.txt
        fi
    done
    '

exec 3<&-
```

The intention was to have `mplayer` and shell `read` accept input from the keyboard, but ins't working out! For that effect, I thought FD 3 will point to keyboard input for both `find` and `xargs` processes. This again gets passed on to the shell that `xargs` execs, where `mplayer` and shell `read` was executed; but it didn't!

What's going wrong here?

Comment: You didn't say exactly how things went wrong, but I'm going to guess that `mplayer` failed to respond to keyboard commands.  If that's the case then it does not necessarily mean that your redirections failed -- it may mean that `mplayer` is using a different method to collect keyboard input than reading from its stdin, and that method does not work when `mplayer` is launched from a non-interactive shell.  In particular, such a process has no controlling terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me! It's the FD 0 -- not 1 -- that should be redirected. A version that works as intended below:

```
exec 3<&0
find /media/jeenu/USB/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 bash -c '
    for i; do
        mplayer -ss 10 "$i"
        read -p "Select? (y/n/q)" -n 1 choice
        case "$choice" in
            [yY]) echo "$i" >> /tmp/selected_songs.txt;;
            [qQ]) break;;
        esac
    done 0<&3
    '
exec 3<&-
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think you're making this harder than it has to be. If you have bash 4, use globstar.

```
shopt -s globstar
for i in /some/directory/**/*.mp3; do
    mplayer -ss 10 "$i"
    read -p "Select? (y/n)" -n 1 choice
    case "$choice" in
        [yY]) echo "$i" >> /tmp/selected_songs.txt;;
    esac
done
```

Even if you don't, you can do this using `find … -exec bash -c 'yourscript' _ {} +` instead of using `xargs`.

(I also changed your `>` to `>>` because I assumed you didn't want to truncate the file at each pass.)

As for understanding the problem, there's all kinds of complex things going wrong here, but I'll point out a few important things:

1. Standard Input is FD 0, but `exec 3<&1` duplicates 1 as 3 and opens it for *reading*.
2. You seem to be trying to change where keyboard input is *going*. That's tricky, because doing that is similar to sending a EOF to an interactive shell. Most shells will close when they encounter that. Instead, consider changing where xargs gets its input, and leave the keyboard alone. (BSD `xargs` has the `-o` option that is relevant. Check your manpage.)
3. You are doing the same redirect for both mplayer and read without a timeout. If you're looping and reading, how do you know where you are in the loop when you provide input?

Comment: I agree that it's more complex that it should be. But I'm more interested in fixing my understanding of how file descriptors work in this situation. And yes, that should have been `>>`. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, just realized that it has to be 0, not 1!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a subshell with bash then you can do this:

```
find /media/jeenu/USB/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 bash <<EOF
#This is a bash subshell
#put your code here
EOF
```